# How to read a property file of a project from another java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

I want to read bean.properties file(in src/conf/bean.properties) of project Test from project Test1 (src/Test1.java). I have referenced Test from Test1 by java build path and using

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/conf/bean.properties"));
```

I am getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\conf\bean.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting your property file in the classpath. In Eclipse it may look like this

```
Project1
+- src
   +- bean.properties

Project2
+- src
   +- ReadPropertiesTest.java
```

Then go to the properties of the Project2, then "Java Build Path", then "Projects" and add Project1 to the list.

Now you can read your file using classloader like this:

```
InputStream stream = ReadPropertiesTest.class.getClassLoader()//
                                             .getResourceAsStream("/bean.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(stream);

// ... closing code here
```

Note the slash `/` before the name of your property file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Sample Code to Read Properties File :-

```
public class ReadPropertiesFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("test.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fileInput);
        fileInput.close();

        Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

or you can Use :-

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
prop.load(in);
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is not possible !!!  You have to specify absolute path to access a file present outside the classpath.
Whenever you write "src/conf/bean.properties" it specifies relative path for that file. Such a file will be searched within classpath only.